# geo within queryfor multipolygon and limit the result for each polygon

Tags: mongodb, geojson

I want to get one document for each polygon when Geple polygons as an array:

```
tempArray.push([
           [
              [long1, lat1],
              [long2, lat1],
              [long2, lat2],
              [long1, lat2],
              [long1, lat1]
            ]
          ]);

db.fmData.find({
              location: {
                $geoWithin: {
                  $geometry: {
                     type: "MultiPolygon",
                     coordinates: tempArray
                  }
                }
              }
            });
```

the above code returns all the document for each polygon, where as i want one document for each polygon. So any improvement in the above query will be a great help. Thank you in advance